# How do I read the following query

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, fetch

I've got an PDO connecting which executes a query, but in don't know how to read the fetched result, the result comes back as an object instead of an array.

```
    $query = $MyPDO->query("SELECT count(ID) FROM score WHERE totalscore>? AND competition=?",$data['totalscore'],$data['competition']);
//$fetch = $query->fetch();
while($fetch = $query->fetch()){
    var_dump($fetch);
}
```

And the result is:

```
object(stdClass)#3 (1) { ["count(ID)"]=> string(2) "27" }
```

Can anyone tell me how to read this? `$fetch["count(ID)"]` did not work, `$fetch[0]` neither.

Comment: $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC), echo $fetch['count(ID)']; More info about the way you retrieve info with PDO is here : http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetch.php

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `SELECT count(ID) as count...` and `$fetch->count`.

Comment: I dowvoted before you edited.. And can't revote now.. So unless you edit I can't revote..

Comment: Yeah I realized late that he used an object as an array. But he should have got an error message which tells the problem haven't he?

Answer (score 2):

Use "->" operator instead "["

Ex.:

```
$column = "count(ID)";
var_dump($fetch->$column);
```

Answer (score 0):

Very Simple

```
$sql = "SELECT count(ID) as counts FROM tablename... ";
$res = $MyPDO->query($sql);
$raw = $res->fetch();
echo $raw['counts'];
```